# Memory-safe way of audio playback in XNA

Tags: audio, memory, xna, soundeffect, soundeffectinstance

I am using XNA's `SoundEffect` class to play sounds in a game project. While the memory management of directly `SoundEffect.Play()`ing effects is relatively clear to me (`SoundEffectInstances` are internally created and added to lists, and their memory is removed upon sound stopping), I would like to know what is advised to do when directly creating `SoundEffectInstances` e.g. to control audio playback (volume etc.) after `instance.Play()`.

Currently, for those sound effects that I need to control after creation I use a special class that in its constuctor creates a new instance by:

`instance = LoadEffect(indexInSoundLibrary).CreateInstance();`

while in the destructor of that class calls:

`instance.Dispose();`

In summary, I use a collection of ~400 sound files (just their filename) that are dynamically loaded whenever needed. Does it make sense to keep a number of `SoundEffectInstances` in memory (e.g. for those audio files in the collection that are typically played by creating a `SoundEffectInstance` (and not by directly using the `SoundEffect.Play()`)?

Are there any limitations of how many `SoundEffectInstances` can be kept in memory at a time?

Just for additional information, I use multiple ContentManagers and regularly `Unload` unused sounds.